# How do I show a popup only while a key is being held? (Like scoreboards in games)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In a WPF project, I have a popup control that I want to show only when the tab key is held down. It should disappear once the key is released. Just like how scoreboards usually behave in video games.

How can I implement this behaviour?

I tried to implement it using PreviewKeyDown and PreviewKeyUp events on the main window as following:

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
   {
        Popup.IsOpen = true;
   }
}

private void Window_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
   {
        Popup.IsOpen = true;
   }
}
```

This approach works fine, but when I hold tab then change the focus to another window before releasing the key, the popup gets stuck. Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: This is what the `Deactivate` event of your Form is for (it gets triggered when your application loses focus to another window.)  See also the `Activated` event.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using `Window.Deactivated` event [Window.Deactivated on Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.deactivated?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to do it procedurally.  When your view becomes visible, add keyboard handlers.  For example

```
private void MyView_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsVisible)
    {
        Keyboard.AddPreviewKeyDownHandler(Application.Current.MainWindow!, OnPreviewKeyDown);
        Keyboard.AddPreviewKeyUpHandler(Application.Current.MainWindow!, OnPreviewKeyUp);
    }
    else
    {
        Keyboard.RemovePreviewKeyDownHandler(Application.Current.MainWindow!, OnPreviewKeyDown);
        Keyboard.RemovePreviewKeyUpHandler(Application.Current.MainWindow!, OnPreviewKeyUp);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the native `SetWindowsHookEx` API to handle key presses that occur when your window isn't focused:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private delegate IntPtr Hookproc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpLibFileName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, Hookproc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private readonly Hookproc _hproc;
    private IntPtr _hhook;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        _hproc = HookProc;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

        const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        _hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _hproc, LoadLibrary("User32"), 0);
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hhook);
        base.OnClosed(e);
    }

    private IntPtr HookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
        const int VK_TAB = 0x09;
        int keyCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
        if (keyCode == VK_TAB)
        {
            if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
                Popup.IsOpen = true;
            else if (wParam == WM_KEYUP)
                Popup.IsOpen = false;
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(_hhook, code, (int)wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mr.Schrödinger: Did you try this?